# should I create table one by one?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
USE dleeat_db;
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    SSN VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Bdate DATE(10) NOT NULL,
    Fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Lname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Minit VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Sex CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Salary INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Department(
    Noofemployees INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Locations VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Number INTEGER NOT NULL
) ;
CREATE TABLE Project(
    NAME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Number INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Location VARCHAR(30)
) ;
CREATE TABLE Dependent(
    NAME VARCHAR(30),
    Sex CHAR(1),
    BirthDate DATE(10),
    Relationship VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Here is my code and it shows this when I run the code:

SQL query: Copy

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    SSN VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Bdate DATE(10) NOT NULL,
    Fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Lname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Minit VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Sex CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Salary INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '(10) NOT NULL,
> Fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
> Lname VARCHAR(30) NOT NU...' at line 3

Comment: I replaced DATE(10) with DATE, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

`DATE(10)` looks wrong to me. Try just `DATE`. You don't need to specify the number of characters in a date field - because it's not stored as a string.

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: I replaced DATE(10) with DATE, but it did not work.

Comment: @DonghyokLee I cannot reproduce it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1976a2c2ac03f0e67d21febe55258074

Comment: I just solved it.... but didn't know how it works.... Thank you so much

Comment: @DonghyokLee please remember to mark the answer as "accepted" if it solved your problem

Comment: @DonghyokLee again please mark this answer as accepted, or otherwise please make clear if/why it didn't solve the problem. If you solved it a totally different way then please add your own separate answer to the question. Don't just leave it hanging, thanks...